# Asking questions in rake tasks

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a rake task that is called from another rake task.

In this rake task I need to ask the user for some text input, and then, depending on the answer either continue, or stop everything from continuing (including the calling rake task).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
task :input_test do
  input = ''
  STDOUT.puts "What is the airspeed velocity of a swallow?"
  input = STDIN.gets.chomp
  raise "bah, humbug!" unless input == "an african or european swallow?"
end
task :blah_blah => :input_test do 
end
```

i think that should work

Comment: pls use STDIN.gets.chomp, to truncate the new line character.. for an exact string match..

Comment: @kaiser , just decide what to do with a if/then/else or unless or even a case type of control structure. In this case I'm raising an exception ( to stop execution as in OP's question ) but you can do anything with the input 

just change the question to be clear you want a yes no in it, one of the other answers does this i think

Comment: Thanks. I'm already doing a Ruby course on CodCademy. I'm just too much PHP for `elsif` and `unless`... :P

Comment: any idea when this code would show "^M" when the enter key is pressed after typing "no" ??

Comment: Do you mean an African swallow or a European swallow? ;-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liIlW-ovx0Y&t=5s

Answer (score 12):

```
task :ask_question do
  puts "Do you want to go through with the task(Y/N)?"
  get_input
end

task :continue do
  puts "Task starting..."
  # the task is executed here
end

def get_input
  STDOUT.flush
  input = STDIN.gets.chomp
  case input.upcase
  when "Y"
    puts "going through with the task.."
    Rake::Task['continue'].invoke
  when "N"
    puts "aborting the task.."
  else
    puts "Please enter Y or N"
    get_input
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

The [HighLine](https://github.com/JEG2/highline) gem makes this easy.

For a simple yes or no question you can use `agree`:

```
require "highline/import"
task :agree do
  if agree("Shall we continue? ( yes or no )")
    puts "Ok, lets go"
  else
    puts "Exiting"
  end
end
```

If you want to do something more complex use `ask`:

```
require "highline/import"
task :ask do
  answer = ask("Go left or right?") { |q|
    q.default   = "left"
    q.validate  = /^(left|right)$/i
  }
  if answer.match(/^right$/i)
    puts "Going to the right"
  else
    puts "Going to the left"
  end
end
```

Here's the gem's description:

> A HighLine object is a "high-level line oriented" shell over an input
>   and an output stream. HighLine simplifies common console interaction,
>   effectively replacing puts() and gets(). User code can simply specify
>   the question to ask and any details about user interaction, then leave
>   the rest of the work to HighLine. When HighLine.ask() returns, you‘ll
>   have the answer you requested, even if HighLine had to ask many times,
>   validate results, perform range checking, convert types, etc.

For more information you can [read the docs](http://highline.rubyforge.org/doc/).

Comment: thank you for posting this, highline solved my problem as well. AWESOME!

Comment: any idea when this code would show "^M" when the enter key is pressed after typing "no" ??

Answer (score 5):

Although the question is quite old, this might still be an interesting (and perhaps little known) alternative for simple prompting without an external gem:

```
require 'rubygems/user_interaction'
include Gem::UserInteraction

task :input_test do
  input = ask("What is the airspeed velocity of a swallow?")
  raise "bah, humbug!" unless input == "an african or european swallow?"
end
task :blah_blah => :input_test do 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do as suggested above, inline:

```
  input = ''
  STDOUT.puts "Are you sure you want to continue?(Y/n)"
  input = STDIN.gets.chomp
  abort "aborting" unless input == "Y"
```